# To store unique element in a collection with natural order

Tags: java, collections

While I was solving a Java test I came up with the following question:

> You need to store elements in a collection that guarantees that no
>   duplicates are stored and all elements can be accessed in natural
>   order. Which interface provides that capability?

```
A. java.util.Map
B. java.util.Set
C. java.util.List
D. java.util.Collection
```

I have no idea what is the right case here? We can store the same element in any of these collections unless in a `Set`, but the `Set` doesn't provide the natural order. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer for that test is **`Set`**   Let's remember that it's asking for an interface that could provide that; given the **right implementation**, the `Set` interface could provide it.

- The `Map` interface doesn't make any guarantees around what order things are stored, as that's implementation specific.  However, if you use the *right* implementation (that is, [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) as spelled out by the docs), then you're guaranteed a natural ordering and no duplicate entries.

  However, there's no requirement about key-value pairs.
- The `Set` interface also doesn't make any guarantees around what order things are stored in, as that's implementation specific.  But, like `TreeMap`, [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is a set that can be used to store things in a natural order with no duplicates.

  Here's how it'd look.

  ```
  Set<String> values = new TreeSet<>();
  ```
- The `List` interface will definitely allow duplicates, which instantly rules it out.
- The `Collection` interface doesn't have anything *directly* implementing it, but it is the patriarch of the entire collections hierarchy.  So, in theory, code like this is legal:

  ```
  Collection<String> values = new TreeSet<>();
  ```

  ...but you'd lose information about what kind of collection it actually was, so I'd discourage its usage.

Answer (score 2):

TreeSet would give you ordering (either natural ordering by default of custom ordering via a Comparator).

To be more general, [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) is the more general interface that offers uniqueness and ordering.

> A Set that further provides a total ordering on its elements. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted set creation time. The set's iterator will traverse the set in ascending element order. Several additional operations are provided to take advantage of the ordering.

Comment: TreeSet is not in the list of interfaces asked by OP. It is also not even an interface.

Comment: `TreeSet` implements `Set` though. None of those would work in the first place, because none of those offers any capabilities at all. They're just interfaces

Comment: @amit well none or the general interfaces mentioned has ordering. Only some of their implementations do.

Comment: List is ordered by definition, though it allows duplicates. If you think the answer is "None of the above, but..." that should be the answer, with explanation why.

Comment: @amit List is ordered by insertion order, not natural order (which is the order defined by implementing Comparable on the element of the collection)

Answer (score 1):

If by natural order, you mean order of insertion, then **LinkedHashSet** is your go to Set implementation.

The correct answers are:
**SortedSet** gives guarantees, regarding natural order of elements.
**TreeSet** is typical implementation

Comment: Again, this is not in the list of possibilities available to OP.

Comment: It's a way to implement Set, with addition of natural order. This is pretty standard pattern

Comment: Yes, but it is not what the question is.

Comment: The answer is, there is no explicit interface within Collection, that gives you this guarantees, but there is a specific implementation of Set, that satisfies your criteria - LinkedHashSet.

Comment: `there is no explicit interface within Collection, that gives you this guarantees` This claim is wrong. `SortedSet` gives you the capabilities

Comment: "natural order" usually means "the order specified by the objects' implementations of Comparable".

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, when choosing from the above `List` is the only of the interfaces that has a defined order of iteration, however it does allow duplicates.

`Set` and `Map` on the other hands, does not allow duplicates (of keys for `Map`), but they also do not define the order of iteration, they are unordered by default, with `HashSet`/`HashMap` being the counter example.

`Collection` allows none.

So, strictly speaking - none of the suggested interfaces provide the desired capability,
However, as others suggested, there are specific implementations of the interfaces that do allow natural order of elements and no duplicates, mainly the [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface and its [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) implementation

---

To further elaborate why `Set` is not a good option, if you have a variable, let it be `mySet`, and you want it to be ordered, users are going to be surprised when you use the `Set` interface, imaigine the following code:

```
public int processMyDataStructure(Set set) {
   //some calculation that assumes set is ordered
   return result;
}
```

and users provide you a `HashSet` as argument - you are going to get a wrong behavior from your method, because `Set` does not guarantee ordering. To avoid it you should have asked for an `SortedSet` rather than `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

I've come over this question yesterday on my interview test and need to comment on that: the question (assuming one of the listed A, B, C or D answers has to be correct) is plainly wrong. **There is no correct answer listed.**

Nothing in [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface guarantees the order in which the elements are to be returned. And there is no such thing, as [Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) would like it in his [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729526/2549722), as ***right implementation*** that could theoretically do the job, because we are not asked for any implementation here, but whether *interface* provides the requested capability.

So, the test question with the answers provided is misguided.

Referring a bit more to [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729526/2549722), there is one more reason for it to be wrong. Specifically, [Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) argues, that *The List interface will definitely allow duplicates, which instantly rules it out.* This argument may be defied by citation from [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) specification saying:

> It is not inconceivable that someone might wish to implement a list that prohibits duplicates, by throwing runtime exceptions when the user attempts to insert them, but we expect this usage to be rare

so in my opinion, any of the answers given is equally wrong, or, as [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729526/2549722) wants it, equally correct, as we are free to write implementation of List (or Map, or Collection) behaving in any way we wish (in boundaries set by an interface specification), but interfaces and their specifications are here to *guarantee* some contract, and this question is really about them, not about possible implementations.